# How to make 2 sequential API calls in Javascript?

Tags: javascript

I intend to retrieve data from two different API's (JSON format), parse and then display parts of each feed on a webpage.

My Javascript and HTML codes look as follows. 
Result: only the second API's data is displayed on the webpage, but not the first.

How can I output both API's data together on the webpage? Thanks!

**My JavaScript Code (apicall.js):**

```js
var apiurl = "api.json"
var apiurl1 = "api1.json"


// CALL THE FIRST API
function setup() {
loadJSON(apiurl, gotData);
}

var output = '';

function gotData(data) {
    var daten = data.datatable.data[0]
    var spalten = data.datatable.columns
    for (var i=0; i < spalten.length; i++) {
    output += '<p>' + spalten[i].name + ':  ' + daten[i] + '</p>';
    document.getElementById('root').innerHTML = output + '</br>';
    }
}

// CALL THE SECOND API
function setup() {
loadJSON(apiurl1, gotData1);
}

var output1 = '';

function gotData1(data) {
    var daten = data.datatable.data[0]
    var spalten = data.datatable.columns
    for (var i=0; i < spalten.length; i++) {
    output1 += '<p>' + spalten[i].name + ':  ' + daten[i] + '</p>';
    document.getElementById('root').innerHTML = output1;
    }
}
```

**My HTML-Code:**

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head> 
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>API Call</title>
    <link href="apicall.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
</head>

<body>
 <div id="root"></div>
 <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/p5.js/0.4.20/p5.min.js"></script>
 <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/p5.js/0.4.20/addons/p5.dom.min.js"></script> 
 <script src="apicall.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Why do you define two functions with the same name?

Comment: do you really have `function setup() {...}` twice? Because that's two functions with the same name, in the same scope - resulting in only the second of them actually existing. (The second over-writes the first, since it has the same name.)

Comment: I have tried to combine both API calls in the 'first' setup function, but then it randomly displays either API1 or API2 data, but never the combination. I also tried to alter the name of one of the functions to setupa(), but it seems that setup() is a function defined in one of the libraries (or something similar), because then only the setup() part seems to work.

Comment: I did some further testing with only a single setup() function containing the two API calls, and either the first, or the second, or sometimes both API calls are displayed. How can I ensure that both feeds are properly loaded before displaying the data?

Comment: Hi F.Marks. I see another problem. When you use .innerHTML, you replace all of the HTML that already exists in that element. In both of your gotData(data) and gotData1(data) functions 
 you are setting the innerHTML of an element with id="root" however the second time you do this you are overriding the last time you did it. So you will only see one of the outputs in the HTML. Do you see what I mean?

Comment: You could use appenChild instead of innerHTML. Here are examples of it: https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_node_appendchild.asp

Comment: Thank you Sara, this is very helpful for me. I have tested the following alternative, and that seems to work, at least IF (!) both API loaded successfully:  in the second function gotData1(): document.getElementById('root').innerHTML = output + output1;

Comment: That was a good idea :) Glad its working now :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What if you increment the `output` instead of just setting it in the second call? This way, I presume you can call both API's in the same `setup` function:

```
var apiurls = [
        'api.json',
        'api1.json'
    ],
    elroot = document.getElementById('root'),
    index = 0;

function setup() {
    loadJSON(apiurls[index], gotData);
}

function gotData(data) {
    var daten = data.datatable.data[0],
        spalten = data.datatable.columns,
        output = '';
    for (var i = 0; i < spalten.length; i++) {
        output = '<p>' + spalten[i].name + ': ' + daten[i] + '</p>';
        elroot.innerHTML += '<br>' + output;
    }
    if (++index < apiurls.length) {
        setup();
    }
}
```

**EDIT:**

I've just implemented a looping for calling `n` API URLs. Since the function `loadJSON` is asynchronous, the callback `gotData` is going to call `setup` again in the end, until all `apiurls` are passed.

Comment: That's a very helpful suggestion, thank you Emanuel, I added that. There still is a problem caused by the 2 identical setup() functions as pointed out by Robin and YoukuleleY, I wonder if I can combine both API calls in one function sequentially.

Comment: Sure, @F.Marks I just edited the answer in order to attend your needs. Check it out, please :)

Comment: I've made another little adjustment. You may try again now, please. Hope it helps.

Comment: Emanuel, this works, with the exception that sometimes the API1 data is shown second in the displayed list, and sometimes first. Is there a way to keep control over the sequence?

Comment: Oh, I see. Are you using this function `loadJSON` from `p5.js`? http://p5js.org/reference/#/p5/loadJSON That's asynchronous... assuming that, I'll think about an improvement here.

Comment: @F.Marks I've updated the answer one more time. I really can't test it in my local environment now, but I hope it works. Do you mind testing it, please?

Comment: You are great Emmanuel, this works perfectly!! I had to change one little thing to make it work, as follows (= instead of +=): `output = '<p>' + spalten[i].name + ': ' + daten[i] + '</p>';`

Comment: Excellent! @F.Marks Glad to know it works! And you're right... I've already updated the answer with this last little change :) Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

```
const apis = [ "api.json", "api1.json" ]
const elroot = document.getElementById("root")

const load = (api) =>
   fetch(api)
     .then(r => r.json())
     .then(j => [ j.datatable.data[0], j.datatable.columns ])

 const concatData = (data) =>
    data.reduce((a, d) => [[...a[0], ...d[0]], [...a[1], ...d[1]]], [[], []])

 const outputTo = (element) => (data) => {
    element.innerHTML = data.map([ daten, { name }] =>`<p>${name} : ${daten}</p>`).join("")
 }

 Promise.all(apis.map(load)).then(concatData).then(outputTo(elroot))
```

Comment: Thank you @Toastal. The part `const concatData = (data) =>
    data.reduce((a, d) => [[...a[0], ...d[0]], [...a[1], ...d[1]]], [[], []])` gives me a brower console error message ´Uncaught SyntaxError: Malformed arrow function parameter list´